# Ubuntu 9.10 repository for diamondback?

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't taken to the new age Ubuntu (10.XX and 11.XX) and I am pretty happy with Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala). Is there any way to install diamondback in Ubuntu 9.10 ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE** : http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source - this works ! I could install ROS-1.4.6 on Ubuntu 9.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9841/ubuntu-9.10-repository-for-diamondback-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

REP 3 (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#diamondback-feb-2011) states that Diamondback is targeted at Lucid through Natty, so there certainly aren't debians being built. You may be able to build from source, however, there may be some libraries which need to be manually updated. Instructions for installing from source can be found on the wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-04-28**:
@tfoote : cool ! .... I was to that ! .... just that I am still installing ROS (1.4.5) on Ubuntu 9.10 ..... I was waiting until that happens ! :-)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-28**:
@Arkpravo, please click the check mark next to correct answers so others know it's satisfactorily answered.  I've done it for you on this question.